# Changing Default Grub Menu, Not Default OS

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, grub-efi, kali

My question is in regards to changing my default GRUB bootoader. Not the boot order, font, image, etc.

I have successfully triple booted both of my laptops. Their default OS's were both Windows 8.1, with UEFI and OEM pre-install. On the first I had all three OS's (Windows 8.1, Ubuntu 15.04 & Kali Linux 2.0) partitioned and installed prior to running Ubuntu boot-repair via live USB. This successfully gave me an Ubuntu GRUB. On the second laptop, It was dual-booted with Windows 8.1 and Kali 2.0 when I ran Ubuntu Boot-Repair via a live USB. This gave me a Kali GRUB default menu.

I would like to switch my second laptops default GRUB to Ubuntu's now that I have added the Ubuntu OS to it (After already running Ubuntu Boot-Repair). Mostly this will be so I can use Ubuntu Grub-Customizer to quickly and easily make changes as OS's are added and/or subtracted.

I'm sure this is an easy fix but I'm stuck and I've spent days trying to read and sort through material, but all I can find is changing fonts, orders, images, etc.

Answer (score 0):

first off all you have to boot from Live-USB with Ubuntu OS on it.

then run this command:

```
 sudo apt-get purge grub grub-pc grub-common
```

when asked select yes.

after that install grub with this command:

```
 sudo apt-get install grub-common grub-pc
```

Ensure that you select “/dev/sda” over the “/dev/sda1″ partition.

reboot your PC and you'll get the default grub2.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. However, I tried running the commands off of an Ubuntu Live USB and still wound up with the Kali GRUB.

Comment: boot to kali and do the second command, Note you'll have no grub after that, now boot to the ubuntu live-USB and do the second command. from there, and add this command after that sudo update-grub. if this worked please let me know to update my answer.

Comment: sorry meant, boot to kali and do the first command. :D

Comment: Still getting the Kali GRUB. Could it possibly have something to do with the pre-installed Windows 8.1 having the sda2 partition be the efi boot loader?

Comment: @c7330x maybe, can you use the EasyBCD app from windows and remove frub from there. then do the boot-usb steps and only do the second command, and the sudo update-grub. and make sure to install it in the same partition as the windows boot-loader.

Comment: I will try that next. I tried the bcdedit edit in Windows cmd to try to change the {bootmgr}, but with no avail. Also when I ran the first command in Kali, the terminal did confirm that 5 or so grub files had been removed. I know we are close, I appreciate all your insight thus far.

Comment: @c7330x you r always welcome, EasyBCD is a gui app, much easyer, keep me updated